# How to solve MQTT connection error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mqtt

I am facing this issue : production.ERROR: PhpMqtt\Client\Exceptions\ConnectingToBrokerFailedException: [1000] Establishing a connection to the MQTT broker failed: Socket error [111]: Connection refused in

here is my env config

MQTT_HOST="broker.hivemq.com"
MQTT_PORT=1883
MQTT_ENABLE_LOGGING=false

Comment: Is this a production error (as per the logs) or does this happen in every environment? My first and best guess would be that you haven't opened the port in your firewall.

Comment: it is an production error

Comment: Then please verify your server is able to access the broker, e.g. with `telnet broker.hivemq.com 1883` or with `openssl s_client -connect broker.hivemq.com:1883 </dev/null`

Comment: i am using cpanel . i can't use telnet on it

Comment: cPanel is only the management platform, what is your hosting provider though? Have you checked whether your hosting provider has some information regarding firewall configuration in its documentation?

Comment: My hosting provider is lws.fr

Comment: Any Idea? Still having the issue

Comment: My suggestion where to look is still the same. I've no experience with cPanel or your hosting provider. If you have troubles to determine whether a firewall is in place, maybe you contact the support of lws.